# How to skip past loops in ddd (gdb)

Tags: c++, c, gdb, ddd-debugger

During many, sometimes inundating,  debugging sessions using DDD, I stumble upon loops. And I keep pressing next to get past it, and if there are many iterations, I just set a break point right after it, and press "continue." Is there any other way to go past loops?

Comment: Thanks for s/passed/past/g ... English is not my first language, although I am unarguably getting better at it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want the "until" command - see the gdb manual at http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation:

> Continue running until a source line
>   past the current line, in the current
>   stack frame, is reached. This command
>   is used to avoid single stepping
>   through a loop more than once. It is
>   like the next command, except that
>   when until encounters a jump, it
>   automatically continues execution
>   until the program counter is greater
>   than the address of the jump.
>
> This means that when you reach the end
>   of a loop after single stepping though
>   it, until makes your program continue
>   execution until it exits the loop. In
>   contrast, a next command at the end of
>   a loop simply steps back to the
>   beginning of the loop, which forces
>   you to step through the next
>   iteration.

Answer (score 3):

I typically use the "continue until here" which sets a temporary breakpoint at that location and immediately continues execution. It is accessed via mouse button 3 which opens a popup menu.